# Mysql Pivot Create

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table in a database that;

```
CREATE TABLE `Comment` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JobId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) )
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is content:

```
Id  JobId   Description
1   1010    Done
2   1010    Success
3   1020    Fail
4   1020    status
5   1030     ..
6   ..      ..
```

and I want to make pivot table like that dynamic:

```
JobId   description1    description2   description3 descriptin4...description[n]
1010    Done            Success           Fail
1020    status          null              null
1030    ..              ..               ..
```

The number of description columns may increase. Any sugggestions?

Comment: Please share all relevant information in text form, not in images. Additionally, explain your expected output further

Comment: Hi  @NicoHaase , I added some information.

Comment: Any suggestion for this?I search for some method and apply, but I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation with case when expression

**[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56da1a2b1ecacba3ddbf8630f0be240c)**

```
select jobid, 
       max(case when description in ('Done','Status') then description end) as description1,
       max(case when description in ('Success') then description end) as description2,
       max(case when description in ('Fail') then description end) as description3
from tablename
group by jobid
```

Comment: @Dekareş - check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56da1a2b1ecacba3ddbf8630f0be240c

Comment: Can we do with Pivot?

Comment: @Dekareş, mysql does not support pivot